# Run Nginx as Non-Root User Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 (xenial).

I want to run nginx as a **non-root, non-sudo** user.

I understand this means I will have to run nginx at a port > 1024.

I've created a user called "nginxuser". I've tried to change the `user` section in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` to "nginxuser".

The top of my `nginx.conf` looks like this:

```
user nginxuser;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {
...
```

Some of my `sites-enabled/default` look like this:

```
server {
        listen 1025 default_server; # 1025 > 1024
        listen [::]:1025 default_server;
```

Upon these attempts, I am still unable to run as my non-root, non-sudo user.

```
$service nginx start
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to start 'nginx.service'.
Authenticating as: Ubuntu (ubuntu)
Password:
```

**How do I run nginx as a non-root, non-sudo user?**

Running nginx on port 80 as root seems **RIDICULOUSLY** insecure. I don't understand why running it on another port is so difficult (I'll use IP tables). Maybe if it wasn't so difficult to configure, less people would be running root on port 80.

Answer (score 0):

A little background

Downloaded the ubuntu source/build from
https://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html

Created $HOME/local/apps

In that directory untarred the file which created nginx-1.14.2

Built the application in $HOME/local/apps/nginx-1.14.2

```
./configure

 make
```

changed nginx.conf so that the server listens on 8080

In $HOME/local/apps/nginx-1.14.2

objs/nginx -p $HOME/local/apps/nginx-1.14.2